# WPF Masked Textbox with a value that does not contain mask

Tags: wpf, textbox, mask, masking

I need a WPF Textbox that displays a phone number as "(555) 555-5555" but has a value of "5555555555".

All of the examples I'm seeing have the ability to mask the control on the UI but that affects the bound property of my view model so that the property value has the extraneous ()- characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about an [IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx)?

Comment: Ya know, I don't know how many times I had thought of IValueConverter but I kept going back to the fact that with *just* a value converter, the user wouldn't be presented with the mask while typing in the value through the UI.  Then as you recommended it, it hit me.  Use both the mask control *and* a value converter.

Answer (score -1):

I am thinking that you will probably have to roll-your-own.  It shouldn't be too difficult, subclass and override to obtain the results you are looking for.