# WPF UserControl with many Controls - how to create Dependency Property that maps to many controls?

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, binding

I have successfully created a UserControl with a Depedency property allowing me to bind to a single TextBox within my UserControl. However Im unsure how to go about doing this when I have many Controls within my UserControl and only want to bind to single Property (built from the values in the many controls)?

The UserControl has 3 textboxes for year, month and date I want to bind this to a single Date Property, so far I have got this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.DateControl"...>
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBox Name="textbox_year" />
        <TextBox Name="textbox_month" />
        <TextBox Name="textbox_day" />
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

What do I need to add to the code behind to make the Date Property got from the three textboxes so in another container using my control can just bind to Date. I realise since my UserControl is the target I have to make a Dependency Property but it seems so complicated..

```
public partial class DateControl : UserControl
{
    public DateControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public DateTime Date
    {
        get
        {
            DateTime dt;
            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(String.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", this.textbox_year.Text, this.textbox_month.Text, this.textbox_day.Text), "yyyy-MM-dd", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
                return dt;
            else
                return DateTime.MinValue;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest using a converter to achieve what you want.

Your user control's XAML will look like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyDateControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:my="clr-namespace:MyDateControl"
             x:Name="root">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <my:DatePartConverter x:Key="DatePartConverter"
                              Date="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=Date}"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBox Name="textbox_year" Text="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=Date, Converter={StaticResource DatePartConverter}, ConverterParameter=year, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <TextBox Name="textbox_month" Text="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=Date, Converter={StaticResource DatePartConverter}, ConverterParameter=month, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <TextBox Name="textbox_day" Text="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=Date, Converter={StaticResource DatePartConverter}, ConverterParameter=day, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

In code-behind you will have only you dependency property:

```
public DateTime Date {
   get { return (DateTime)GetValue(DateProperty); }
   set { SetValue(DateProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty DateProperty = 
   DependencyProperty.Register("Date", typeof(DateTime), typeof(MyDateControl), 
      new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(DateTime.Now, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
```

And the converter will look something like this:

```
public class DatePartConverter : Freezable, IValueConverter
{
    public DateTime Date {
        get { return (DateTime)GetValue(DateProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DateProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Date", typeof(DateTime), typeof(DatePartConverter), new UIPropertyMetadata(DateTime.Now));


    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        DateTime date = (DateTime)value;
        string datePartType = (string)parameter;

        string result;

        switch (datePartType) {
            case "year":
                result = date.Year.ToString().PadLeft(4, '0');
                break;
            case "month":
                result = date.Month.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0');
                break;
            case "day":
                result = date.Day.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0');
                break;
            default:
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Unknown date part type (ConverterParameter)");
        }

        return result;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        string datePartValue = (string)value;
        string datePartType = (string)parameter;

        DateTime result;

        switch (datePartType) {
            case "year":
                result = new DateTime(int.Parse(datePartValue), Date.Month, Date.Day);
                break;
            case "month":
                result = new DateTime(Date.Year, int.Parse(datePartValue), Date.Day);
                break;
            case "day":
                result = new DateTime(Date.Year, Date.Month, int.Parse(datePartValue));
                break;
            default:
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Unknown date part type (ConverterParameter)");
        }

        return result;
    }

    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore() {
        return new DatePartConverter();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm I dont think so, using a converter looks like a lot more work - I dont think it is neccessary to create 3 extra bindings to get the one date esp. given the bindings will 90% of the time fail to make a date - see my answer..

Comment: These bindings are not "extra". In your code you are doing these binding manually in the code... While in my case all the conversion logic is encapsulated in a converter keeping the main user control logic simple. And these binding will not fail as long as you put the right conversion logic in the converter.

Comment: The main user control logic is simpler without the bindings I think. The bindings will needlessly run your converter every time a key pressed. No matter, its just not what im looking for.

Comment: @Fëanor - Well, compare amount of logic in the user control itself in your case and in mine. In my case it is just bindings, while in yours there is whole lots of logic in the code behind. What you actually do is called "manual binding" (handle changed events and transfer values). As for "needlessly run your converter every time a key pressed" - I don't think that there might be any performance issues... But if it bothers you, you can change UpdateSourceTrigger to LostFocus in the binding decoration and it will run only when the control looses focus.

Comment: @Fëanor - Also, if you ever decide to implemented validation on the text boxes (e.g. when user types not valid day or year, you might want to display a red border around the text box), with standard bindings it will be very easy because WPF already has infrastructure for that working via bindings. But in your case you will have to do everything manually.

Comment: Actually I use Validation Rules already (im only showing that part im interested in) - it is easy becuase they take the Date from DateControl.Date - remember DateControl is my Control like a TextBox is a control so validation rules can be on the binding between my DateControl and ViewModel - I have included the XAML below so you can understand

Comment: @Fëanor - I'm talking about different validation rules, the ones on each text box inside your control.

Comment: I understand, I found it easier to make textboxes only allow numbers and only so many thereafter if the values dont make a valid date i do set the border red and the tool tip describing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I personally would approach something like this.  Normally, I would move the members out into a separate logic class and include some other validation in the setters.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public MainWindow()
  {
     InitializeComponent();
     DataContext = this;
  }

  public DateTime Date
  {
     get
     {
        DateTime dt;
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(String.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", DateYear, DateMonth, DateDay), "yyyy-MM-dd", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
           return dt;
        return DateTime.MinValue;
     }
  }

  private string year = "2011";
  public String DateYear
  {
     get { return year; }
     set { if (year == value) return; year = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("DateYear"); NotifyPropertyChanged("Date"); }
  }

  private string month = "11";
  public String DateMonth
  {
     get { return month; }
     set { if (month == value) return; month = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("DateMonth"); NotifyPropertyChanged("Date"); }
  }

  private string day = "11";
  public String DateDay
  {
     get { return day; }
     set { if (day == value) return; day = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("DateDay"); NotifyPropertyChanged("Date"); }
  }

  #region INotifyPropertyChanged
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string info)
  {
     if (PropertyChanged != null)
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
  }
  #endregion
}
```

And the xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label>Date:</Label>
    <Label Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding Path=Date}" />
    <Label Grid.Row="1">Year</Label>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=DateYear}" />
    <Label Grid.Row="2">Month</Label>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=DateMonth}" />
    <Label Grid.Row="3">Day</Label>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=DateDay}" />
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Sorry but what you have shown is not a UserControl which I want to reuse elsewhere and bind the Date property of the control to my ViewModel. Like one would bind a TextBox's Text propperty to their ViewModel..

Comment: ahhh, should have read more closely.  Should be a fairly simple transform, unfortunately, I can't look at it again till later.

Answer (score 0):

If the case you mentioned is for DateTime, then you can go for Masked TextBox.

[WPF Masked Textbox with a value that does not contain mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729851/wpf-masked-textbox-with-a-value-that-does-not-contain-mask)

Comment: thats not what I want as has only one control such as one TextBox whereas mine has many forwhich one cannot use a IValueConverter which I am already very familiar with..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the TextChanged events on the TextBoxes to set the date:

```
public partial class DateControl : UserControl
{
    public DateControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        textbox_year.TextChanged += RecalculateDate;
        textbox_month.TextChanged += RecalculateDate;
        textbox_day.TextChanged += RecalculateDate;
    }

    private void RecalculateDate( object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e )
    {
        DateTime dt;
        if ( DateTime.TryParseExact( String.Format( "{0}-{1}-{2}", textbox_year.Text, textbox_month.Text, textbox_day.Text ), "yyyy-MM-dd", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt ) )
            SetValue( DateProperty, dt );
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register( "Date", typeof( DateTime ), typeof( DateControl ), new PropertyMetadata( DateTime.MinValue ) );

    public DateTime Date
    {
        get { return (DateTime)GetValue( DateProperty ); }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="DateControlApp.DateControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBox Name="textbox_year" />
        <TextBox Name="textbox_month" />
        <TextBox Name="textbox_day" />
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

And the container:

```
<StackPanel>
    <DateControlApp:DateControl x:Name="dateControl" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=dateControl, Path=Date}" />
</StackPanel>
```

It's very simplistic of course. The rest is left as an exercise for the reader :)